# SAPUI5 Routing after Parameter Change no longer working

Tags: routes, sapui5

i have an ui5 app with different views (App/Main - createTravel - travelDetails). Navigating through em via Router. Now i changed the Parameter of one Route from mandatory to optional, means from "{destination}" to ":destination:".

And now the routing no longer works. **There's no error in console**. It just jumps back to the Main View.

The Route looks like:

```
{
                "name": "travelDetails",
                "pattern": "traveldetails/:destination:", //<-was {destination}
                "target": ["travelDetails"]
            }
```

The Target:

```
"travelDetails": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "viewName": "travelDetails",
                    "level": 3
                },
```

In my Controller:

```
this.oRouter.navTo("travelDetails", {}, true);
```

Somebody got an Idea?

I also tried:

```
this.oRouter.navTo("travelDetails");
this.oRouter.navTo("travelDetails", {destination: ''}, true);
this.oRouter.navTo("travelDetails", true);
```